# For what values of c will the iteration $x_{n+1} = g_c(x_n)$ converge to $\alpha_c$

Tags: numerical-methods

Consider the equaction $x=g_c(x)\equiv cx(1-x)$, with c a nonzero constant. This equation has two solutions, and we let $\alpha _c $ denote the nonzero solution. What is $\alpha _c$?For what values of c will the iteration $x_{n+1} = g_c(x_n)$ converge to $\alpha_c$ (provided that $x_0$ is chosen sufficiently close to $\alpha$)?

Can someone give me a hint how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** This is the [Logistic Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map), which has generally a complicated behaviour. For $1<c<3$ the sequence of $x$ converge to $a_c= \frac{c-1}{c}$ which can easily  be computed from $c(1-a_c)=1.\;$ For most $c > 3.56995$ there is chaotic behaviour.